# Error: FormatException: //localhost:3030 - Hi can anyone help me

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart

I am try to make a simple request using an api request in my capstone project (developing web application with flutter)
I am not really familiar with this problem.

The code of the request is this:

```
final response = await http.post( Uri.http(registrationUrl, '/registration'), headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: jsonEncode(regBody));
```

Error:
`Error: FormatException: //localhost:3030 C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49      throw_ C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 243:`

I've tried it using https and http, and changing my URI path too, but still not working.

Comment: This is my code final response = await http.post(
          Uri.http(registrationUrl, '/registration'),
          headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
          body: jsonEncode(regBody));

Comment: Can you display the result of the request when you use another client?

Comment: No sir.. but my configuration is perfectly fine. I've tried sending request using postman, and it is working well.

Comment: Try using your IP address and not "localhost"

Comment: I've also tried to use my ip address sir..

Comment: Exactly what is the value of `registrationUrl`?

Comment: http://192.168.8.102/registration and also I've tried to use localhost but it didn't work sir